# Azure Cognitive Services Speech in Blazor (server) site-- critical error

Tags: c#, blazor, azure-cognitive-services

Code works on dev machine on VS.  But on deployment I get:

`System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found.`

I looked in the build directory, and found the file:
`Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.csharp.dll`

My problem-- why is dev site not also crashing, but only Windows VM is crashing?

Can anyone suggest why it's looking for the wrong file?  I'm hosting the site on a Windows VM, and installed the C++ redists already.

Comment: "... or one of its dependencies" - did you install something on the dev machine? Did you check dependencies of the package?

Comment: When you install the Cognitive Services Speech Nuget package, it doesn't list any dependencies at all.  But the tags listed with it are highly suspicious: `Microsoft, Speech, Cognitive, Services, native, C++, C#, .NET, .NETStandard`  This looks suspciciously like it's C#, but with C++ Invokes going on in the background.  So I installed the current C++ redists on my VM server as a Hail Mary-- didn't work.

Comment: As for what is on my Dev computer-- who knows?  But I CAN say that the published project has `Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.csharp.dll` and not `Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.dll`  I just don't know why, or what it means.  I'm starting to think it will be better to run an API in another language like Python.  I'm running a full Windows Server VM, so I can probably do that.

Comment: Also-- the Speech Nuget is listed as version 1.25, whereas anything .net I'd expect to be at 7.01 or 7.02 now.

Comment: Is your project WebAssembly project or conventional .NET project? Currently Azure Speech SDK does not support WASM, see https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/930

Comment: It's a Blazor server project.  I've realized that I really don't want to run the SDK server side even if I could-- if I had a couple dozen users it would probably shut down the page.  HOWEVER, my issue is figuring out why it won't run on the server-- it seems to be dependencies, but just installing the C++ redists doesn't stop the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use Azure Cognitive Services Speech in Blazor, if you create a server app, the code runs in the server and you wouldn't be capturing the mic of the client but the server (if it even has one).
And if you create a Web Assembly app, wasm can not open communication with the mic of the client (I've tried)